# When I convert a PDF to plain text, the text is scrambled

Tags: pdf, copy-paste

When I convert a PDF created in MiKTeX to plain text, all diacritics are at the wrong place. I need to send my thesis to online antiplagiator checking page.

Example:

> pr´ce a diskusia mˆˇu tvorit aj jednu y y y a oz samostatn´ ˇast a spoloˇne

How can I fix it?

Ok, here is some working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <---- Like this?
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\linespread{1.2}

\begin{document}     
ľščťžýáíéäúôň %these are some misbehave characters 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably by using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. But as you didn't show your code this is pure guessing.

Comment: This is in my preamble:                             \documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\linespread{1.2}

Comment: @MikeS, that does not provide the text, please update your question with all the inteformation. Comments are not really for posting large pieces of code

Comment: @MikeS, try Ulrikes suggestion, (I usually add it before `inputenc`). Then I seem to get the correct text out both from copying from Adobe Reader and via `pdftotext` on the command line. Everything done via TeX Live 2014 on Linux

Comment: You mean like in my edited example? It did not work for me (from Acrobat to Word). Text is still wrong and kind of pixelated... :-(

Comment: If the font is pixelated: Install the cm-super package or use `\usepackage{lmodern}` to switch to a type1 font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using `glyphtounicode` support file (even with Czech/Slovak related IL2 font encoding) from TeX Live for some time now, I cannot test it with MiKTeX, unfortunately. We run:

```
pdflatex mal-sk.tex
pdftotext -enc UTF-8 mal-sk.pdf
```

The result is: `1 ľščťžýáíéäúôň`, it shows the page number and the document content. I enclose the code. Please, try it if it fits your needs.

```
% pdflatex mal-sk.tex
% pdftotext -enc UTF-8 mal-sk.pdf
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[slovak]{babel}
\linespread{1.2}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
\begin{document}     
ľščťžýáíéäúôň
\end{document}
```